# Which reals are Lebesgue measures of regions in $\mathbb R^n$ defined by inequalities involving polynomials with integer coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, lebesgue-measure

Let $a$ be a real number.  What are necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a positive integer $n$ and a finite set of polynomials $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ with integer coefficients in $n$ variables such that $a$ equals the Lebesgue measure of the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid p_j(x)\geq 0\text{ for }j=1,\dots,k\}$?

This question was inspired by the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental, i.e., is not a root of any univariate polynomial with integer coefficients.  Nevertheless, $\pi$ can be defined in terms of a polynomial with integer coefficients --- namely, it is the area of the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid 1-x^2-y^2\geq 0\}$.  Can, say, $e$ be expressed in this sort of way?

Comment: Aren't these numbers periods of Kontsevich and Zagier?

Comment: Indeed, it seems to me these are precisely periods.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to answer the question completely.

Comment: In standard usage, one writes either $\text{“for } j=1,\ldots,k\text{”}$ (without the word “all”) or $\text{“for all } j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}\text{.”} \qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy, thanks, I've edited accordingly.